# How does the + operator work for combining delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates

For example:

```
delegate void SomeDelegate();

SomeDelegate a = new SomeDelegate( () => Console.WriteLine("A") );
SomeDelegate b = new SomeDelegate( () => Console.WriteLine("B") );

SomeDelegate c = a + b;
```

In the last line, what does `a + b` translate to? I'm just curious how I would add them without using the `+` operator.

Comment: I didn't know that this is valid C# code.

Comment: @rekire: Well the first line would be outside a function and the next 3 would be in one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172(v=VS.80).aspx - Search for addition:

> A delegate can call more than one method when invoked. This is
>   referred to as multicasting. To add an extra method to the delegate's
>   list of methods—the invocation list—simply requires adding two
>   delegates using the addition or addition assignment operators ('+' or
>   '+='). For example:

```
MethodClass obj = new MethodClass(); 
Del d1 = obj.Method1; 
Del d2 = obj.Method2; 
Del d3 = DelegateMethod;

//Both types of assignment are valid. 
Del allMethodsDelegate = d1 + d2; 
allMethodsDelegate += d3;
```

> At this point allMethodsDelegate contains three methods in its
>   invocation list—Method1, Method2, and DelegateMethod. The original
>   three delegates, d1, d2, and d3, remain unchanged. When
>   allMethodsDelegate is invoked, all three methods are called in order.
>   If the delegate uses reference parameters, the reference is passed
>   sequentially to each of the three methods in turn, and any changes by
>   one method are visible to the next method. When any of the methods
>   throws an exception that is not caught within the method, that
>   exception is passed to the caller of the delegate and no subsequent
>   methods in the invocation list are called.

**Update**

Both delegates derive from [System.Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) You can use the `combine()` methods to add two delegates together.

Comment: Yeah I know addition works. I'm asking how the addition works. For example, how would you simulate the exact same behavior without using the + operator. Is there a function to use?

Comment: Do you have to cast it like this: `SomeDelegate c = (SomeDelegate)Delegate.Combine(a, b);`? Does the + operator do that internally as well?

Comment: Note that System.Predicate<T> is a delegate, and thus you can add two predicates. However the return value of the combination is the result of the last one added, not a logical AND or OR of each predicate. (It's a pity Predicate doesn't overload operator+ to perform a logical combination of results.)

Answer (score 5):

It is done using [`Delegate.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30cyx32c(v=vs.110).aspx) static method.

```
SomeDelegate c = Delegate.Combine(a, b) as SomeDelegate;
```

When using `+=` operator it is just the same actually.

```
// This is the same...
eventSource.onEvent += OnEvent;

// ...as this.
eventSource.onEvent = Delegate.Combine(
    eventSource.onEvent,
    Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventSource.OnEvent), this, "OnEvent")
    ) as EventSource.OnEvent;
```

[`MulticastDelegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate(v=vs.80).aspx) class (the class behind `delegate` keyword) do have a list of invocations, but this list is immutable. Each time you combine delegates with the `+=` operator, a new `MulticastDelegate` instance get created combining the invocation list of the former two Delegate objects.