# Why do I get a clone of Action<> when getting from dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I have the following dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, Action<GameObject, int, int, int, int>> eventDictionary;
```

I wish to keep a dictionary of Actions (basically delegates) so that whenever I wish to subscribe to an event name, I can subscribe to the same event for all my subscribers.

This is my function to listen to a certain event string:

```
public static void StartListening(string eventName, Action<GameObject, int, int, int, int> listener)
{
    Action<GameObject, int, int, int, int> thisEvent = null;
    if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
    {
        thisEvent += listener;
        // the code reaches this 
    }
    else
    {
        thisEvent += listener;
        instance.eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
    }
}
```

Now I try

```
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);

// Log here to get how many subscribers there are to the event "Move"
// Result: only 1 listener
```

Only the first added listener will actually register, the rest "disappear" after adding them. I debugged this error for nearly 4 hours, before finally testing to see if maybe the line `thisEvent += listener;` was malfunctioning. When I added a remove and subsequent add back to the dictionary,

```
public static void StartListening(string eventName, Action<GameObject, int, int, int, int> listener)
{
    Action<GameObject, int, int, int, int> thisEvent = null;
    if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent))
    {
        thisEvent += listener;
        instance.eventDictionary.Remove(eventName);
        instance.eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
    }
    else
    {
        thisEvent += listener;
        instance.eventDictionary.Add(eventName, thisEvent);
    }
}
```

the delegates finally got added as expected.

```
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);
EventManager.StartListening("Move", Moved);

// Log here to get how many subscribers there are to the event "Move"
// Result: 4 listeners
```

This is one of the most nonsensical errors I have ever gotten. Aren't all values in a dictionary that aren't strings, ints, etc. supposed to be retrieved by reference, not by value? Why do I get a clone of the Action here, rather than a reference?

PS:
GameObject is a Unity class.
This is my Moved function:

```
public void Moved(GameObject invoker, int x, int z, int tx, int tz)
{
    //Some code here
}
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35968889/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-delegates-are-immutable-in-c)

Comment: What would you expect to happen in your else statement since thisEvent is most likely null (if it has a class type)

Comment: Also you might be surprised to learn that `string` is an "immutable" reference type.

Comment: I expect the else statement to run once (which it does), in order to create the dictionary entry.

Comment: I believe that the += operator will create a new instance before setting it back to `thisEvent`, so you need to update the dictionary entry as well, like this `instance.eventDictionary[eventName] = thisEvent;`

Answer (score 3):

> This is one of the most nonsensical errors I have ever gotten. Aren't all values in a dictionary that aren't strings, ints, etc. supposed to be retrieved by reference, not by value? Why do I get a clone of the Action here, rather than a reference?

When you call `TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent)` you are providing a reference to which the `Dictionary` will write the value. You are not getting a reference to what is inside the `Dictionary` (I mean, you are not getting a deep pointer to the `Dictionary` structure, meaning that assigning to it will NOT modify the `Dictionary`).

---

Perhaps some confusion might stem from the fact that a delegate is a reference type. *And yes, you get a reference to the same delegate object, not a new one.* However, delegate addition returns a new multicast delegate.

*By the way, `string` is a reference type.*

See:

- [How to combine delegates (Multicast Delegates) (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/how-to-combine-delegates-multicast-delegates)
- [How does the + operator work for combining delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13549043/402022).

---

> I'm just left wondering why it is designed that way. Almost all languages have dictionaries that give you back a reference when getting objects. How else should I get objects when I am not sure if it is null?

Memory safety. There will be no chance of orphan pointers or similar with this design.

Although, it can be considered an oversight not to have an alternative API for updates, such as [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>.AddOrUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netframework-4.8). `Dictionary` is not meant to be thread safe, and you can accomplish the same thing, even if less efficiently... that would explain why it was not considered necesary.

If you are looking for an alternative (other than `ConcurrentDictionary`) you can use a mutable reference type. Such as `List<Delegate>` for example. In `TryGetValue(eventName, out thisEvent)` you would still be providing a reference to which to write the `List<Delegate>`, however, you can then mutate it. However, you still have to deal with initializing it, which you would do when the key is not present. *You would not have nulls.*

```
if (instance.eventDictionary.TryGetValue(eventName, out var thisEvent))
{
    thisEvent.Add(listener);
}
else
{
    instance.eventDictionary.Add
    (
        eventName,
        new List<Action<GameObject, int, int, int, int> {listener}
    );
}
```

---

> This also makes me wonder, is it a deep or shallow clone?

If you are storing a value type, you get a copy of the value type.

If you are storing a reference type, you get copy of the reference. I would not call that cloning. It is just another reference to the same object.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but I'm just left wondering why it is designed that way. Almost all languages have dictionaries that give you back a reference when getting objects. How else should I get objects when I am not sure if it is null?

This also makes me wonder, is it a deep or shallow clone?

Comment: In normal C#, I get a reference to the item stored in the dictionary... https://dotnetfiddle.net/1zc8rr

Comment: @ps2goat this is not abnormal C#, simply the delegate is not mutable, while the `List<int>` is mutable. In both cases you get a reference to the object, but not a reference to the storage in the dictionary (as in, setting to it will not replace the contents of the dictionary). See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MbjGJH (compare with using `+=` on the delegate, we are doing assignment, in case that is not clear... you can write `thisEvent += listener` like this `thisEvent = thisEvent + listener`).

Comment: Yeah. Theraot is correct. It works totally fine if u dont use TryGetValue... https://dotnetfiddle.net/nGCLt1

Comment: Ok. At least with Unity 5, it used dotnet when running on a Windows machine locally, and mono when not on Windows. So I consider that to be a possibility for `abnormal`ness.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer, Theraot. So quick and thorough. I almost feel like I should have debugged less and just asked here haha

Comment: @ps2goat I think it makes sense, given Theraot's answer. When I do my reassignment (`thisEvent = thisEvent + listener`) all I am doing is just changing what my local variable points to, not what the dictionary value points to.

Comment: That's fine, I'm just scraping some knowledge for myself in the process. I definitely agree with the approach to use a List or something similar to store multiple things. In my initial review of the code, I thought you were simply adding listeners to an event, which isn't the case.

Comment: @TheForgot3n1 With modern C#, it could be possible to have an API that returns a reference such that assigning to it modifies the internal structure. And without unsafe code. See [Ref returns and ref locals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns). There are restrictions around it, so that the compiler can ensure that what is being referenced is available for the scope. (to be continued...)

Comment: @TheForgot3n1 (...continuation) Although that what is being referenced stays available does not mean that it will continue to be part of the structure. For example, if we are talking of a tree and a branch is removed, your reference could point to something that is no longer in the tree you think it is. Also, if you are getting a reference to an array, and the code moves values in it (to keep them compact, for example), then you may end with a reference to a different value. I would rather get a callback with a ref with the guarantee that it stays valid for the callback, than ref return.

Comment: @theraot I had no idea you could do that. Good article link! Yeah regular references usually suffice, but this is good to know about.